# BATCH: How to echo string containing '&' char to a file

Tags: windows, build, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write to a file a URL string that has the '&' char in it (using simple 'echo'),
problem is that it's a saved char in the command prompt so it fails.

Is there any way to tell the command prompt that it's part of the string.

Example:

```
echo www.google.com/search=make&peace > love.txt
```

I'll get an error indicating that "peace" is not a recognized command.

Thanks!

Comment: see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777547/dos-echo-writing-a-text-string-that-contains-a-backslash-isues-with-assignment

Answer (score 20, accepted):

cmd uses ^ as the escape character, so

```
echo www.google.com/search=make^&peace > love.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Just enclose the URL in Quotes:

```
echo "www.google.com/search=make&peace" > love.txt
```

Comment: This will put the quote marks in the file, which is probably inappropriate.