# Writing a text string that contains a backslash, issues with assignment of the variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want the bat file to take this text `\Music\TheArchive\Aeph & Neonlight\Aeph & Neonlight - Space Truckers - 7b - 173.26.mp3` and write it into a new row in the existing text file `baseplaylist.m3u`

So far I have this:

```
set "texty=\Music\TheArchive\Aeph & Neonlight\Aeph & Neonlight - Space Truckers - 7b - 173.26.mp3"
echo %texty% >>C:\Music\Playlists\baseplaylist.m3u
```

but it does not work. I know the issue is due to the characters in the text that I am trying to copy, but I don't know how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the operator **&**, in that cases you will need to expand the variable or scape the operator or enclosing the "echo" string with another double-quotes... But the solution in your case is so simple:

```
set "texty=\Music\TheArchive\Aeph & Neonlight\Aeph & Neonlight - Space Truckers - 7b - 173.26.mp3"
<nul Set /P "string=%TEXTY%" >>C:\Music\Playlists\baseplaylist.m3u
```

**PS**: Using **SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** is a bad practice when you are playing with filenames (especially when they contain the character **!** ) so try to never use the expansion, all can be done without expanding vars (ALL), enabling delayedexpansion is the easy **and bad** way to done the tmost things, but not the only way.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: An interesting solution with SET /P, though it has its limitations. Not normally an issue with file names, but SET /P will trim leading spaces from the output on Vista and Windows 7. The variable name is not required when used like this. `<nul set /p "=%texty%"` works just fine.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your delayed expansion advice. Delayed expansion can be an invaluable tool for writing robust and efficient batch code. The only significant issue to worry about is when expanding FOR variables containing `!` while delayed expansion is enabled - not an issue in this case. If you would like to debate the pros and cons of delayed expansion, then I am happy to engage in a chat session.

Comment: Totally awesome guys. that change works a treat. I knew it would be something simple. Its just hard when you are getting started. Thanks very much for the help! :)

Comment: @dbenham   1. I don't need to debate anything because my years of experience tells the thru, what I've said about Setlo... is the reality if you agree or disagree. 2. the set /P only trim the first blanck space ONLY in win Vista/7/8, in XP for example not, and the "texty" variable don't have space at the start so... all stills good. bye

Comment: Hi Electro Hacker. I have been using that code and have identified a problem that I was not having before. When using the echo command with the double >> symbol the text was always written to a new line in the destination file. The code change that you presented seems to keep writing the result into the last existing row in the destination file. Is there some change that I can make to that code line that can make it always write the text to a new line in the destination file. I have been trying to figure it out but am getting nowhere. Thanks :)

Comment: @user1887696 - SET /P does not terminate output with `<CR><LF>`. You can use `echo(` after the SET /P to write the new line. Most people use `echo.`, but `echo(` is actually safer. `echo.` can fail under certain unusual circumstances. You might also try using delayed expansion with ECHO instead - it really is a good solution, despite Elektro Hacker's opinion.

Comment: @ElektroHacker - Umm, your "truth" is an opinion not held by many experienced batch developers, and simply bad advice. And your argument of experience means nothing - I doubt you have more experience with batch than I have, but that doesn't mean anything either. An opinion is worthless (and frowned upon) on this site without concrete examples to back it up. But so is debate frowned upon on this site, which is why I suggested a chat session.

Answer (score 3):

Backslash has nothing to do with your problem. Nor is there a problem with your assignment of the variable. :-)

Your problem is the `&` character - it is the compound command operator that allows you to run multiple commands on the same line of input. You want the `&` to be a literal, but it is being treated as an operator when you try to ECHO it. For example, `echo this&echo that` prints 2 lines of output to the screen: "this" followed by "that".

A batch line must be parsed before it can be executed. The parser must identify commands and operators. The expansion of `%texty%` occurs before the commands and operators are parsed, so the parser thinks the next token after `&` is a command.

There are many special characters that can cause similar issues: `|` `>` `<` `)` `&` `^`.

There are two ways to force the batch parser to treat a special character as a literal: 1) enclose it in quotes, or 2) escape it with `^`.

```
echo this&echo that
echo "this & that"
echo this ^& that
```

results:

```
this
that
"this & that"
this & that
```

In your SET statement you have the entire assignment enclosed in quotes, so it is properly treated as a literal. You can prove it to yourself by putting the command `set texty` after your set assignment - it will print the current value of texty to the screen and you can see that it is your desired value.

But when you echo the value it is no longer quoted, so the parser treats the `&` as an operator and you have your failure.

You could `echo "%texty"`, but then you would get quotes in your output.

You could change the definition of texty to include the escape character.

```
set "texty=\Music\TheArchive\Aeph ^& Neonlight\Aeph ^& Neonlight - Space Truckers - 7b - 173.26.mp3"
```

But that is a pain. Thankfully there is a simple solution - delayed expansion of a variable occurs after the commands and operators have been parsed, so you no longer have to worry about special characters.

Delayed expansion must be enabled before it can be used using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. Then you enclose the variable name in exclamation points instead of percents.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "texty=\Music\TheArchive\Aeph & Neonlight\Aeph & Neonlight - Space Truckers - 7b - 173.26.mp3"
echo !texty! >>C:\Music\Playlists\baseplaylist.m3u
```

Now the line is parsed for commands and operators before `!texty!` is expanded. So ECHO properly prints the literal value of texty.

Comment: Thanks very much dbenham for making the time to explain this in such detail. Much appreciated mate.

Comment: Hey dbenham. I have been using that code and have identified a problem that I was not having before. When using the echo command with the double >> symbol the text was always written to a new line in the destination file. The code change that you presented seems to keep writing the result into the last existing row in the destination file. Is there some change that I can make to that code line that can make it always write the text to a new line in the destination file. I have been trying to figure it out but am getting nowhere. Thanks :)

Comment: @user1887696 - I suspect you are using Electro Hacker's suggestion. My suggestion will write a complete line of text to the file, assuming the last line of the existing file is terminated with `<CR><LF>` (end of line on windows).